# Determining a suitable subclass to store specific type of data in Python

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have a generic set of attributes (e.g. of type string and integer) and I would like to use the following django models to store them:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    item            = models.ForeignKey('Item')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @staticmethod
    def get_subclass_by_type(type):
        TEXT_TYPES = ["text", "string"]
        INTEGER_TYPES = ["integer", "number"]
        if type in TEXT_TYPES: 
            return TextAttribute
        if type in INTEGER_TYPES:
            return IntegerAttribute

class TextAttribute(Attribute):
    value            = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class IntegerAttribute(Attribute):
    value            = models.IntegerField()
```

Is there any clean & simple way I've missed to define the types in the subclasses directly? Something like:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    item            = models.ForeignKey('Item')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @staticmethod
    def get_subclass_by_type(type):
        <do something>

class TextAttribute(Attribute):
    TYPES            = ["text", "string"]
    value            = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class IntegerAttribute(Attribute):
    TYPES            = ["integer", "number"]
    value            = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: classmethod expects the first parameter to be the class. Example: `def foo(cls, *args **kwargs)`

Comment: Yes, but it's a staticmethod which doesn't expect the class.

Comment: Doh! My apologies. This is a case of NCS - No Coffee Syndrome

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define your method get_subclass_by_type like the following

`@classmethod
def get_subclass_by_type(cls, type):
    for subcls in cls.__subclasses__():
        if type in subcls.TYPE:
            return subcls`

Haven't tested this code, but i think it should work.

Comment: Works so far, just thought about a cleaner way for that issue than meta programming. Something I missed related to inheritance.